# Does the upgrade process perform enough 'clear caches / templates_c' or should it?

Tags: upgrade

We have hit issues after upgrades that require additional "drush cc all" and/or "clear out templates_c" to make me wonder if the upgrade script could be taking care of this better?

Would it be possible to have the script run an extra one of each at the end of the process?

Comment: Perhaps a permissions issue? I usually run upgrades as the webuser (in our case): sudo -u apache

Comment: Agree current behaviour is not always enough - eg https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/why-have-all-my-custom-civi-fields-stopped-showing-up-in-drupal-view   I've had issues with Stripe IPN's after upgrades that are fixed by another cache clear.